# Validate asp.net calendar date is in future using asp.net validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, validation

So I want to use the CompareValidator to make sure a ASP Calendar objects selected date is a date in the future. I'm not sure how to do this, but this is what I have so far. When I try to do this though it tells me that I can't validate the calendar object?

.aspx code:

```
 <asp:CompareValidator ID="ValidateEventDate" ControlToValidate="Calendar1" Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
    Type="Date" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Can't pick a date in the past">

  <asp:Label ID="eventDate" ForeColor="Black" runat="server" 
   Text="Select a Date"></asp:Label>

<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
    onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" BackColor="#FF0000"></asp:Calendar>
<br />
```

Here is my code behind:

```
  protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ValidateEventDate.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

    }
```

Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [Calendar Custom Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415206/calendar-custom-validator)
The standard validators aren't very useful with the calendar control.